# WPF ListView GroupStyle GridViewHeaderRowPresenter doesn't hide original headers

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

[image]

I have a listview that uses `GroupStyles` where the `ColumnHeaders` are shown in each group.  This works fine.

I would however like to **hide** the original **ListView** `ColumnHeader` (seen at the top of image) and just show Headers within the groups.

How can I separate them so it only show in the groups?

The GroupStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="GroupingSerialStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GroupingBase}">
    <Setter Property = "Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Expander Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpandedAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="2">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text=" # "/>
                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Visibility = "Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0"
                DataContext="{Binding View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ListView,1}}"
                Columns="{Binding Columns}"       
                ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyleABCD}"
                ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
                ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector}"
                AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding AllowsColumnReorder}"
                ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding ColumnHeaderContextMenu}"
                ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding ColumnHeaderToolTip}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin = "15,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Edit:** Further the column headers shall presented with custom colors for each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved through the `ColumnHeaderContainerStyle`. If you set an empty `Template` at `GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle` and use your styled `GridViewColumnHeaderStyleABCD` for your `GroupItem` it should work.

I tried the following, that only displays column headers at the group items with customized `Background`.

```
<ListView BindingGroup="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestItems}}">
    <!-- ### custom coloring column headers ### -->
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Column.(YourNamespace:BgHelper.CustomBackground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                <!-- Empty: ListViews header shows nothing -->
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <!-- ### custom coloring column headers ### -->
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Parameter0}" Header="Par0" YourNamespace:BgHelper.CustomBackground="Pink" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Parameter1}" Header="Par1" YourNamespace:BgHelper.CustomBackground="Green" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Margin="2">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text=" # " />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                                    Columns="{Binding Columns}"
                                                    DataContext="{Binding View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, ListView, 1}}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                    Visibility="Visible" />
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="15,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

To customize your column header colors you could use an `AttachedProperty` as follows:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class BgHelper
    {
        #region Fields

        public static DependencyProperty CustomBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomBackground",
                                                typeof (SolidColorBrush),
                                                typeof (BgHelper),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)));

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public static SolidColorBrush GetCustomBackground(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (SolidColorBrush) element.GetValue(CustomBackgroundProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCustomBackground(DependencyObject element, SolidColorBrush value)
        {
            element.SetValue(CustomBackgroundProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then I extended my example above with setting the `CustomBackground` and using it at `GridViewColumnHeader` style. I marked the new/edited lines with comments.

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate the suggestion..  Your answer does work - I confirmed this and actually had this working previously - you did answer what I asked.  Unfortunately I failed to mention that I am trying to conditionally color headers depending on the column.  In my image you can see gray, but some other columns are orange or blue depending on the column.  This is where it seems to break.  I have tried DataTemplateSelector, ValueConverter, style selector, but have not been able to get something workable.  I will continue to try here...

Comment: Finally found something that would work.  In the GroupStyle, duplicate all of the columns from the GridView and specify a HeaderContainerStyle there that can reference different colors. E.G.:

Comment: thank you for the new edits - I got it to work and it is a far better implementation than what I had.  A small note that the GroupStyle should be ContainerStyle rather than HeaderTemplate or the records will not collapse - just the headings.  Thanks again for the great insight!

Answer (score 0):

@WPFGermany was correct.  However, in my original question I forgot to add that for the headers within the GroupStyle I also needed to show different background colors for some of the column headings.  I was able to get this to work by duplicating all of the columns in the GroupStyle and pointing each ColumnHeaderStyle to a unique color.  Perhaps there is a better way but for now this works for me.  Here is the partial GroupStyle to illustrate:

```
           <Style x:Key="GroupingNcpCheckStyleRoot" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GroupingBaseRoot}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpandedData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="2">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="HeaderCheckBox" Margin="0,0,6,0" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" # "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="15,0,0,0"

                                                DataContext="{Binding View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, ListView, 1}}" 
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                Visibility="Visible"   >
                                    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.Columns>
                                    <!--NOTE: must explicitly create the collection-->
                                    <GridViewColumnCollection>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header=" " Width="60" >
                                                <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyleTEST1}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TargetHeaderColor}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,-1,0" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate >
                                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Id, StringFormat='# {0}'}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>

                                            <GridViewColumn Header=" Show " >
                                                <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyleTEST1}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DifferentHeaderColor}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,-1,0" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate >
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeInReport}" HorizontalAlignment="center"></CheckBox>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: take a look at my updated answer. And don't foregt to upvote

Comment: Refer to the previous answer - the new edits make it much better than what I came up with:)